# How to change password of LDAP in c#/.NET using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard

Tags: c#, .net, ldap

I try Change the password of LDAP using Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard(last version),but
it does not works.

This is my code:

```
      if (Con.Connected)
            Con.Disconnect();


        Con.Connect(_config);


        string userToChange = "myUser";

        LdapAttribute attribute = new LdapAttribute("unicodePwd", password);

        LdapModification modification = new LdapModification(LdapModification.Replace, attribute);

        Connection.Modify(userToChange, modification);
```

The message error is: "Operations Error"

what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

first you must connect via SSL then bind to AD

```
var ldapConn = new LdapConnection();
ldapConn.SecureSocketLayer = true;
ldapConn.UserDefinedServerCertValidationDelegate += (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
ldapConn.Connect(YOUR_AD_URL, LdapConnection.DefaultSslPort);
ldapConn.Bind(LdapConnection.LdapV3, AD_USER_LOGIN, AD_USER_PASSWORD);
```

important thing is `AD_USER_LOGIN` must contain `ROLE`, which can modify AD data.
then

```
ldapConn.Modify(YOUR_DN,
    new LdapModification(
            LdapModification.Replace,
            new LdapAttribute("unicodePwd", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"\"{NEW_PASSWORD}\""))
        )
    );

ldapConn.Disconnect();
```

Enclosing the password within double quotes is IMPORTANT.

https://github.com/dsbenghe/Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard/issues/31

Comment: here YOUR_DN is in format "CN=USER_LOGIN,OU=Users,DC=YOUR_DC,DC=YOUR_DC"

Comment: UserDefinedServerCertValidationDelegate is obsolete now.  Better use:                     var options = new LdapConnectionOptions();
options.ConfigureRemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnRemoteCertificateValidation);
            var ldapConn = new LdapConnection(options)
            {
                SecureSocketLayer = true
            };

                                                        
 private static bool OnRemoteCertificateValidation(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Kuat Khamitov is suitable for password reset operations. For example, when user forgot password and admin must reset it, not knowing user old password.

For situations when it is necessary for the user to change his password himself, use the script, taking into account the old password.

```
var options = new LdapConnectionOptions();
            options.ConfigureRemoteCertificateValidationCallback(OnRemoteCertificateValidation);

            var ldapSecureConn = new LdapConnection(options)
            {
                SecureSocketLayer = true
            };

            ldapSecureConn.Connect(host, LdapConnection.DefaultSslPort);

            ldapSecureConn.Bind(LdapConnection.LdapV3, $"{domain}\\{samAccountName}", oldPassword);

   var ldapModifications = new LdapModification[2];
        var deletePassword =
            new LdapAttribute("unicodePwd", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"\"{oldPassword}\""));
        ldapModifications[0] = new LdapModification(LdapModification.Delete, deletePassword);

        var addPassword = new LdapAttribute("unicodePwd", Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes($"\"{newPassword}\""));
        ldapModifications[1] = new LdapModification(LdapModification.Add, addPassword);

        ldapSecureConn.Modify(distinguishedName, ldapModifications);
```

...

```
  private static bool OnRemoteCertificateValidation(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }
```